# Angular 4 Update object within subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my Angular 4 application I have a component that has an object called selectedEmployee.  This object has a property called EmploymentStatuses which is an array of objects.  If the user triggers a function, I send a request to the server which returns a collection of updated statuses. I want to replace the EmploymentStatuses array with the data coming back from the server.  Here is my code:

```js
doUpdateEmployeeEmploymentStatusEntry(model: any) {            
        var self = this;
        this.api.put('employees/UpdateEmployeeEmploymentStatusEntry', model).subscribe((res: any) => {                
            var statuses = res.json();
            self.resetEmploymentStatuses(statuses);
        }, (error: any) => {
            ...
        });
    }
    resetEmploymentStatuses(statuses: Array<any>) {
        this.selectedEmployee.EmploymentStatuses = new Array<any>(); <-- this line trigger the error

        for (let item of statuses) {
            ... some other unrelated code

            this.selectedEmployee.EmploymentStatuses.push(item);
        }
    }
```

Everything runs fine and the UI updates correctly, however, I am getting the following error in the console:

```html
errors.ts:42 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Unexpected literal at position 2
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:795)
    at zone.js:847
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.ts:288)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:602)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:503)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1427)
    at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1445)
```

I tried wrapping **self.resetEmploymentStatuses(statuses);** in setTimeout, but I am still getting the error.  I also tried calling detectChanges() on the ChangeDetectorRef, but without success.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: As @Nickolaus said, it's really hard to know what's going on in here. Also, a quick google search of that error code `Unexpected literal at position` shows how this is a common issue when parsing Dates from a string. Maybe you are parsing dates somewhere in your code? Maybe that `some other unrelated code` is not that unrelated....

Comment: @olivarra1,  Brilliant.  It was exactly that.  The data coming back from the server contained a date field which was causing an issue.  Once I converted into a js date, the error disappeared.  Please make this an answer so I can accept it.  Thank you.